# I'm creating a program to accept N numbers and find its sum using list

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python. I'm creating a program to accept N numbers and find its sum using list. How can i add numbers to a list dynamically? This is what I'm at now.

```
n=int(input("enter the value of n"))
list=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    a=int(input("enter the value of number",i+1))
    list.append(a)
Sum=0
for num in list:
    Sum=Sum+ num
print("sum is",Sum)
```

Comment: aaaaand what's your question? ok: last != list. And you have to use append, you cannot used indexing if the list is empty.

Comment: How do I use append?

Comment: There are documentation, tutorials, and textbooks that demonstrate the basic functions.  You haven't posted an attempt; where are you having trouble?

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. The variables `Sum` and `sum` are not the same.

Comment: You shouldn't use ```list``` for a variable name unless you understand what the consequences are.

Comment: ```input``` only takes one argument: change ```input("enter the value of number",i+1)``` to ```input("enter the value of number")```

Answer (score 1):

After getting `n` using `n=int(input("enter the value of n: "))`, you can add `n` inputs to the list using `list comprehension`:

```
numbers=[int(input()) for i in range(n)]
```

To get the sum of these numbers, simply use the built-in function `sum()`:

```
total=sum(numbers)
```

Full code:

```
n=int(input("N:"))
numbers=[int(input()) for i in range(n)]
total=sum(numbers)
print("sum is: ",total)
```

Example input:

```
enter the value of n: 5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Output:

```
sum is: 15
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've updated the code above using append. But CMD shows line 5 is syntax error

Comment: What is line 5 of your code, the program i wrote for my answer was only 4 lines?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone but I corrected what i did wrong and came up with a code that suits me best.

```
n=int(input("enter the value of n"))
lst=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    a=int(input("enter the number"+str(i+1)))
  list.append(a)
Sum=0
for num in lst:
    Sum=Sum+ num
print("sum is",Sum)
```